# Best way to read/edit/add the googlecode wiki offline

Tags: wiki, mercurial, version-control

I finally after too much of pondering started my project on googlecode. One of the best features I liked about googlecode was the revision control for wiki, where I can add/edit the wiki pages locally offline and then commit/push later.

I have pulled the wiki to my local repository, is there any good googlecode-wiki-toolbar-attached editor for googlecode wiki, as from my knowledge evey wiki has its own syntax for writing.

Or if someone is also using a local repository for wiki.code.google, what practice are they following for writing the document for online collaborations.

Comment: This bug report lists alternatives: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Code Wiki uses a syntax similar to MoinMoin](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiFAQ#What_syntax_are_you_using_in_the_wiki?). Hence, any offline editor with MoinMoin support should get you started. For instance syntax highlighting is available for [Vim](http://moinmo.in/VimHighlighting), [Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/moinmoinwikitext/), [Emacs](http://moinmo.in/EmacsForMoinMoin), ... search for *moinmoin FOOEDIT* if *FOOEDIT* is your favorite editor.